# R language can't put my number, it's too big

Tags: r, dataframe, null

I don't know why
But I have

```
df1 <- na.omit(marketcap[,c('id','Marketcap')])
df1$Marketcap <- as.numeric(df1$Marketcap)
df1$formatted_market_cap <-  paste0(df1$id,'\n','$',format(df1$MarketCap,big.mark = ',',scientific = F, trim = T))
treemap(df1, index = 'formatted_market_cap', vSize = 'Marketcap', title = 'Cryptocurrency Market Cap', fontsize.labels=c(12, 8), palette='RdYlGn')
```

And in the result: How to remove Null

[image]

Comment: Try paste0(df1$id,'\n', format(df1$MarketCap,big.mark = ',',scientific = F, trim = T))

Comment: Provide your data using `dput(df1)`

Comment: the same, someone told me that I need to use int64 package or smth like that

Comment: structure(list(id = c("Bitcoin", "Dogecoin", "Ethereum", "Litecoin", 
"Monero", "Nem", "Stellar", "xrp"), Marketcap = c(641899161593.76, 
30552518423.82, 271028619181.2, 9277626785.3, 3986737880.19, 
1202315485.08, 6049985280.38, 30722840710.51), formatted_market_cap = c("Bitcoin\nNULL", 
"Dogecoin\nNULL", "Ethereum\nNULL", "Litecoin\nNULL", "Monero\nNULL", 
"Nem\nNULL", "Stellar\nNULL", "xrp\nNULL")), row.names = c("Bitcoin", 
"Dogecoin", "Ethereum", "Litecoin", "Monero", "Nem", "Stellar", 
"xrp"), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0):

To include large number we can do,

```
df$formatted_market_cap = paste(df1$id, '',formatC(numb, format = "e", digits = 2))
treemap(df, index = 'formatted_market_cap', vSize = 'Marketcap', title = 'Cryptocurrency Market Cap', fontsize.labels=c(12, 8), palette='RdYlGn')
```

Data

```
structure(list(id = c("Bitcoin", "Dogecoin", "Ethereum", "Litecoin", 
"Monero", "Nem", "Stellar", "xrp"), Marketcap = c(641899161593.76, 
30552518423.82, 271028619181.2, 9277626785.3, 3986737880.19, 
1202315485.08, 6049985280.38, 30722840710.51)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Bitcoin", 
"Dogecoin", "Ethereum", "Litecoin", "Monero", "Nem", "Stellar", 
"xrp"))
```

[image]

Comment: but there aren't my numbers here

Comment: modified the answer to include numbers